# CSS Scrolling Tab Bar

Tags: html, css

I have a tab bar with a variable number of tabs, I want it to be scrollable, preferably without javascript. I've been toying with CSS animations to make it work and almost have a working result but when you try to move back and forth it gets very jumpy and doesn't like to work once you've reached the end of the tab bar.

The fiddle demonstrates it and the desired behavior should be obvious.

https://jsfiddle.net/c1rde8nL/2/

Does anyone have a suggestion how I can get the scroll arrows to scroll properly?

---

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="tabView">
      <nav>
        <nav>&lt</nav>
        <nav>&gt</nav>
        <nav>
          <label>Tab 1</label>
          <label>Tab 2</label>
          <label>Tab 3</label>
          <label>...Lot's more tabs...</label>
          <label>Tab 49</label>
          <label>Tab 50</label>
        </nav>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tabView > nav {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tabView > nav > nav:last-of-type {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.tabView > nav > nav:first-of-type {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
}
.tabView > nav > nav:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.tabView > nav > nav:last-of-type {
  animation: slide 10s linear 1;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.tabView > nav > nav:first-of-type:hover ~ nav:last-of-type {
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
.tabView > nav > nav:nth-of-type(2):hover + nav:last-of-type {
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    margin-right: -100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
}

/* theming */
.tabView {

}
.tabView > nav {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.tabView > nav > nav {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.tabView > nav > nav > label {
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: #b5b5b3;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 1em;
  border-top-left-radius: 1em;
}
.tabView > section {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
}
```

---

**Bonus Question:** Does anyone know why the tabs overflow? I can't get them to remain hidden, I know it's something stupid I'm missing I just haven't gotten it working for some reason.

Comment: `animation-fill-mode: backwards` might not do what you're expecting - have a look here: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-css-animation-fill-mode-property/

Comment: as well as `animation-direction: reverse` is actually initiating from the "opposite" state, as you can see an example of here: https://jsfiddle.net/oqwqLn92/

Comment: on the `:first-of-type:hover` rule I put `animation-fill-mode: backwards` and `animation-direction: reverse` because hovering over that element should reverse the animation since it's the "scroll to beginning" arrow, and after the animation is complete on that scroll arrow, it should end on the first frame which is the beginning. 
I've tried to make two separate animations but that doesn't work and just want to pause and reverse this one animation repeatedly and in the middle. It seems so simple but doesn't want to behave.